# Is the Black Stone alive?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

> Ibn Abbas narrated that:
>
> The Messenger of Allah said about the (Black) Stone: "By Allah! Allah will raise it on the Day of Resurrection with two eyes by which it sees and a tongue that it speaks with, testifying to whoever touched it in truth." ([Jami` at-Tirmidhi, Book of Hajj, Hadith 961](https://muflihun.com/tirmidhi/9/961))

What's the meaning of this hadith? Is the Black Stone currently alive or will this only occur on Judgement Day like the way the hands, tongues and feet of disbelievers will be brought to life and testify against them?

I'm confused about this bcuz it has lead to shirk. Also this is no different to ancient pagan superstition that stones have inherent powers.

Comment: Define alive and then explain what it is that you are asking that is not obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you do not realize this, but *almost everything* will be brought to testify on the Day of Judgement. For example, in the Quran, Allah says about the earth itself:

> When the earth is shaken with its [final] earthquake,
>
> And the earth discharges its burdens,
>
> And man says, "What is [wrong] with it?" -
>
> That Day, it will report its news
>
> Because your Lord has commanded it. (99:1-5)

The question of whether that thing is "currently alive" is meaningless. In what sense do you mean "alive"? Clearly, they are not alive in the sense that they are made up of living cells.

But, everything in the universe *is* alive in a sense we do not understand. We know this because Allah says in the Quran among other similar things, that the stars and trees prostrate to Him (55:5).

You said "I'm confused about this bcuz it has lead to shirk" however I don't see how exactly it is Shirk. As you know, we do not worship the Black Stone .

Comment: Alive as in does it have a soul or is it inhabited by an angel? I've asked about this once regarding whether the stone has consciousness over here : https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/59460/what-is-the-authenticity-of-this-report-that-the-black-stone-has-consciousness

Comment: @Afiq I can't say for sure since I have never seen such a thing (whether objects have souls) discussed. (Also why would angels "inhabit" them?) However, a soul is not needed to testify. As you yourself noted, body parts will testify but of course that does not mean they each have a soul.

Comment: I've been hoping for an answer with regards to wether the stone is an angel. The report can be found in the book "Lore of Light" by Amina Adil. A similar report with variations can be found in Mustadrak Hakim, vol. 1 pg. 457.

Comment: @Afiq The hadith is apparently very weak: https://hadithanswers.com/an-unauthentic-narration-regarding-umar-radiyallahu-anhu-and-the-hajarul-aswad/. I do not think it is a Sunni belief that the Black Stone is an angel